# This matrix is an attractor?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find for which values of $\gamma$ the matrix A is an attractor:

$$
        A=\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & -1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        -1 & 0 & \gamma \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

I know that a matrix is an attractor iff its generalized eigenvalues have negative real parts.

However, the characteristic polynomial is $p(\lambda)=(\lambda^2+1)(\lambda-\gamma)$.
Therefore, there are two eigenvalues with zero real part $(\lambda=\pm i)$, then for every value of $\gamma$, A is not an attractor, am I right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the definition of attractor?

Comment: yes, didn't you see the definition I wrote?

Comment: For positive values of $\gamma$, $A$ is not an attractor.  By attractor I assume that you mean that the system $\dot{x} = Ax$ system is stable.

Comment: I know what a generalized eigenvector is. I don't know of generalized eigenvalues. And if you are talking of the differential system $X'=AX$, the term attractor applies to vectors (the origin $0$ in particular) such that (definition) and not to the matrix itself. As far as I know...